# Bouncy Castle's TlsServerProtocol.Accept() hangs when port accessed as HTTP

Tags: c#, sockets, bouncycastle, tls1.2

I am trying to use BouncyCastle's API to add support for TLS into my code, but the behavior I am getting is really weird. After accepting socket, creating `TlsServerProtocol` instance and calling `.Accept()` on it one of the following two things happen:

- Either I get successfully connected [that is when I tell the browser it's `HTTPS://` page]
- Or it hangs at the `TlsServerProtocol.Accept()` call and never does anything else - just wasting resources and open socket - [that is when I access it as `HTTP://`]

Is there a way to add a timeout to this function so in case of failure / wrong input data the function returns? Thanks

Minimal example (server listening at :12346):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Tls;
using Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;
using Org.BouncyCastle.X509;

namespace CentralVPS
{
    public class MinExample
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            new MinExample().Start();
        }
        
        private TcpListener Listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 12346);

        public void Start()
        {
            Listener.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                Socket socket = Listener.AcceptSocket();
                Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    await HandleClient(socket);
                });
            }
        }

        public async Task HandleClient(Socket socket)
        {
            NetworkStream stream = new NetworkStream(socket);
            stream.ReadTimeout = 1;
            stream.WriteTimeout = 1;
            TlsServerProtocol protocol = new TlsServerProtocol(stream, new SecureRandom());
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Accepting... " + stream.CanTimeout);
            protocol.Accept(new SampleTlsServer(
                    File.OpenText("./localhost.crt"),
                    File.OpenText("./localhost.key")
                ));
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Done!");
            protocol.Close();
            stream.Close();
        }
    }

    public class SampleTlsServer : DefaultTlsServer
    {
        private readonly Certificate _certificate = null;
        private readonly AsymmetricKeyParameter _rsaPrivate = null;

        public SampleTlsServer(TextReader cert, TextReader privateKey) : base()
        {
            var cer = (X509Certificate) new PemReader(cert).ReadObject();
            _certificate = new Certificate(new[] { cer.CertificateStructure });
            _rsaPrivate = (AsymmetricKeyParameter) new PemReader(privateKey).ReadObject();
        }

        public override TlsCredentials GetCredentials()
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("GetCredentials");
            return new DefaultTlsSignerCredentials(mContext, _certificate, _rsaPrivate);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Accepting... True # HTTP://
Accepting... True # HTTPS://
GetCredentials    # HTTPS://
Done!             # HTTPS://
```

Cert and private key generated with: `openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -x509 -sha256 -days 3650 -nodes -out localhost.crt -keyout localhost.key`

Wireshark (3x HTTP requests): [image: wireshark]

Comment: Most likely the connection is closing.  I would use a sniffer like Wireshark or fiddler to see exactly what is happening.  With sniffer you can see the TLS version.  TLS the server sends a certificate block with names of possible certificates.  The client looks up the certificate names in the stores.  The certificate you are using has to be in the list of certificates sent from the server.

Comment: Don't think it's because the socket is closed, see the added WireShark. Looks like a bug in the BountyCastle, or I just can't use it (not that I can find examples of how to online). Anyway since I am not able to get the answer, I started rewriting the client in C++ using OpenSSL, that should be bug free.

Comment: The source IP and destination IP cannot be the same address.  You will notice a [FIN] which indicates the TCP connection closed.  Normally the server will listen on 127.0.0.1 (loopback) or IPAddress.Any.  Client will connect to the IP address of machine.

Comment: You're right about the FINs, but the source and destination IPs can and are the same e.g. when you host and access the server on the same machine. You were probably thinking of ports, those can't be the same under the same IP.

Comment: No.  Even when you connect on same machine the source and destination must be different.  That is why the Ethernet specification includes a generic end point (like IPAny) and a Loopback 127.0.0.1.  So when you are on same machine the source and destination are different.